# Does Windows copy file permissions with copied files?

Tags: windows-7, windows, acl

When I copy a file from one location to the other will the destination keep the original permissions or will it take the copied files permissions?

Comment: It depends on what the destination is & who is in charge of it. It is trivial to take ownership of a file & set your own permissions, if you are an admin on the destination device.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense.  "When I copy a file from one location to the other with the destination keep the original permissions" seems like it needs a few commas. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in Windows, copied files will not retain permissions set to them explicitly. For instance, a file C:\Temp\temp.txt with an explicit Write permission set for a certain user, will not have this permission on it's copied instance.

The copied instance will receive any inherited permissions applicable for its new path. For instance, any inherited permissions on C:\Temp will still apply when temp.txt is copied as temp2.txt.

So, the closest approximation of an answer to your question would be that the file would take "the copied file's permissions."

Comment: what a baffling answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you're making a new copy, it inherits the destination folder's ACLs. There is a hidden Explorer setting, `ForceCopyAclwithFile`, that would tell it to copy the ACLs as well.

- [How permissions are handled when you copy and move files and folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310316)

Some vaguely related articles:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/24/717181.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/09/24/10451467.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/10/14/10647632.aspx

---

On the one hand, your question's title – "Are windows security settings on the file or on the location?" – doesn't have any meaning.

If the settings were on a file, it doesn't mean they'd be copied *automatically*. And if the settings were on a location, it doesn't mean they *couldn't* be copied. In practice, the copy function first duplicates the contents, then adjusts timestamps, then duplicates ACLs...

On the other hand, it would be important for *other* security mechanisms beyond ACLs, for example, mandatory access control such as SELinux or AppArmor (both on Linux). That is, SELinux attaches MAC information to files, and it is preserved when renaming a file; meanwhile, AppArmor rules are written based on literal paths, no matter what file is there.